# Typescript: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FormDataEntryValue'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, multipartform-data, form-data

I have:

`const file = formData.get('documents[]')`

What type is file?

`const file: FormDataEntryValue | null`

I need to access to `file?.name`.

and i got:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FormDataEntryValue'.

Comment: If `file` is null, how do you expect to get the `name` property of it? Also, [`FormDataEntryValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEntryValue) is defined as either a string **or** a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File). A string does not have a `name` property.

Answer (score 15):

FormDataEntryValue is defined as an union of File and string:
`type FormDataEntryValue = File | string;`

Thus you need to check first that the variable is indeed a File:

```
if (file instanceof File) {
  console.log(file.name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`FormData.get()` returns a value of type `string | File | null`.

If you know that it is going to be a file, use:

```js
const file = formData.get('documents[]') as File
```

Here is a reference, https://dev.to/deciduously/formdata-in-typescript-24cl

Answer (score 1):

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'FormDataEntryValue'.

As error says, looks like `key` passed in the FormData.get() or the `name` property in `file` variable doesn't exist.

The `get()` method of the `FormData` interface always returns the first value associated with a given key from within a `FormData` object.

Hence, As per your code. Looks like documents is an array of object. Hence, you can access the name by `file[0]?.name` instead of `file?.name`

```
formData.append('documents', '[{name: "alpha"}]');

const file = formData.get('documents')

const fileName = file[0]?.name // returns alpha
```